# Which services does "services.AddRazorPages();" actually add?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

As far as I understand `services.AddRazorPages()` takes care of adding a bunch of different services, but which ones does it actually include?

I know it already comes with the AntiRequestForgery functionality and tag helpers, but are there others?

I was looking at the [globalisation documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#implement-a-strategy-to-select-the-languageculture-for-each-request), which is set up like this:

```csharp
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

services.AddMvc()
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
```

Can I simply add these lines, or does `services.AddRazorPages()` also take care of initializing the globalisation features?

Comment: The `AddViewLocalization` extension method belongs to `IMvcBuilder`, so you need to call `AddMvc` to be able to register the service, even though your application is Razor Pages and makes no use of views or controllers: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/346/using-resource-files-in-razor-pages-localisation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/1d5d144c12d13b2672352e43ba883d5be3d95cf4/src/Mvc/Mvc.RazorPages/src/DependencyInjection/MvcRazorPagesMvcCoreBuilderExtensions.cs)

A quick scan doesn't turn up anything about globalisation features.

Another way to find out is to make a simple testpage for dumping all registered services. You can inject IServiceProvider and get them.

And when in doubt, you could use `services.TryAdd(....)`